# Floating point precision golang

Tags: go

Was curious as to why the following produces two different values.

```
    fmt.Println(51.231576 * math.Pi / 180) // 0.8941596821857065
    fmt.Println(float64(51.231576) * math.Pi / 180) //0.8941596821857064
```

I understand this is tiny differences but would like to understand why.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with *untyped* [constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants). An *untyped* floating point constant can hold a value with a much higher precission than a *typed* `float64` constant.

So on the second line, in your *typed* constant expression the multiplication yields a float with a precision much smaller than the multiplication in the *untyped* constant expression on line one.

> Implementation restriction: Although numeric constants have arbitrary
>   precision in the language, a compiler may implement them using an
>   internal representation with limited precision. That said, every
>   implementation must:
>
> - Represent integer constants with at least 256 bits.
> - **Represent floating-point constants, including the parts of a complex constant, with a mantissa of at least 256 bits and a signed binary exponent of at least 16 bits.**
> - Give an error if unable to represent an integer constant precisely.
> - Give an error if unable to represent a floating-point or complex constant due to overflow.
>     Round to the nearest representable constant if unable to represent a floating-point or complex constant due to limits on precision.

See related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512022/965900

Comment: seems crazy that `pointB.Lat * math.Pi / 180 !== pointB.Lat * (math.Pi / 180)` also

Comment: @amwill04 that's not Go related, that's the imprecision of IEEE-754 64-bit. Here's [go](https://play.golang.com/p/RrMYh53Aq0x) and here's [rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d76f8a48492c9394955eeeab85d8da9e). I don't have the links but js and swift return the same thing for me as go and rust. You can try other languages.